# last image repeating in gridview

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, gridview

I want to display an image in grid view cell on specific condition andthe  condition fails image not to be display.

```
 <asp:GridView ID="gvWrkLogVW" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        onrowdatabound="gvWrkLogVW_RowDataBound" 
        >
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" Width="20px" Height="20px" />
                </ItemTemplate>

            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

On row data bound

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            Image img = (Image)e.Row.FindControl("Image1");

            for (int i = 0; i < dtWorkLogDeatils.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                if (dtWorkLogDeatils.Rows[i]["email"].ToString() == "True")                   
                {                        
                    img.ImageUrl = "/images/mail_send.png";
                }
                else
                {
                    img.ImageUrl = "";                        
                }
                }
            }
```

the last binding image is repeating all the  columns.How to assign the image to particular cell

Comment: if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
                {
                    DataRowView drv = (DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem;
    
                    if (drv["email"].ToString() == "True" )
                    {
                        Image img = (Image)e.Row.FindControl("Image1");
    
                        img.Visible = true;
    
                    }
                    
                }
            }

Comment: Did you answer your own question?

Comment: yes ps2. I found the answer